# How to show loading image (animated .gif file) inside autocomplete textbox using MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have implemented Autocomplete textbox in my asp.net MVC3 application, but I am unable to show loading image inside textbox during search.
My code is

> **Javascript**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtPONO").autocomplete({
        source: "/Transection/GetPONO",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#hdnPurContID").val(ui.item.id);
        }
    });
});


</script>
```

> **View**

```
<div style="float: left; padding: 9px 5px 5px 5px; width: 80px; vertical-align: middle"
                                class="fieldHead">
                                Enter @Html.LabelFor(l => l.PurchaseContract.AOPLPONO)
                            </div>
                            <div style="float: left; width: 200px; padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PurchaseContract.AOPLPONO, new { @id = "txtPONO", @class = "textbox", @style = "width:100%" })
                            </div>
                            <div style="float: left; width: 50px; padding: 4px 0px 0px 5px;">
                                <img alt="search" src="../../Content/images/Search.png" />
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PurchaseContract.PurContID, new { @id = "hdnPurContID" })
                            </div>
```

I want to show a small loading image inside textbox on right side

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a css class like this.

```
.loading
{
    background:url('path to your image') no-repeat right center;
}
```

Now trigger to the search option and open options for autocomplete

```
$("#txtPONO").autocomplete({
        source: "/Transection/GetPONO",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#hdnPurContID").val(ui.item.id);
        },
        search: function(){$(this).addClass('loading');},
        open: function(){$(this).removeClass('loading');}

    });
```

OR

Even better solution would be just using the css class

```
.ui-autocomplete-loading { background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat right center }
```

jQuery `ui-autocomplete-loading` automatically runs the loading image for the duration of loading

Hope it helps

Comment: the proper solution is the second one listed above.  Just beware that you may run into an issue with CSS specificity where another background style may override yours.  In that case you can do something like adding the element `input.ui-autocomplete-loading { background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat right center; }`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this-

```css
.loadinggif {
    background:url('http://www.hsi.com.hk/HSI-Net/pages/images/en/share/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat right center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id='inputsource' />
<br>
<button onclick="$('#inputsource').addClass('loadinggif');">Show Loading</button>
<br>
<button onclick="$('#inputsource').removeClass('loadinggif');">Hide Loading</button>
```